# How to copy files in a while loop after getting results returned by find command?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, operating-system, command-prompt

```
usage: cp [-R [-H | -L | -P]] [-fi | -n] [-apvXc] source_file target_file
       cp [-R [-H | -L | -P]] [-fi | -n] [-apvXc] source_file ... target_directory
```

I am trying to loop through every single file with a certain extension (eg:txt) in the system found by the find command. While it loops through each file, I would like to check if there's already an existing file with the same name in the user's desired directory. Else, it will copy the file. However, the cp command does not work. This is what I have so far:

```
find . -type f -name "*.$fileType"| while read file; do
    fname=`basename $file`
    echo $fname
    echo $file
    if [ -e "$path/$directory/$fname" ]; then
        echo "$fname exist"
    else
        cp $file $path/$directory
    fi
done
```

[image: ERROR MESSAGE]

Comment: 1) Run your script through [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net) and fix what it points out. 2) If you still need help after that, please edit your question to include the full script and run in code format (i.e. indented 4 spaces so it's displayed literally rather than all mushed together like it is now).

Comment: shellcheck.net now also has "apply this fix" link! WOW!

Comment: Fixed! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have spaces in your variables, you should properly enclose them in quotes.

```
find . -type f -name "*.$fileType"| while read file; do
    fname="$(basename $file)"
    echo "$fname"
    echo "$file"
    if [ -e "$path/$directory/$fname" ]; then
        echo "$fname exist"
    else
        cp "$file" "$path/$directory"
    fi
done
```